# LuaLaTeX - string contains an invalid utf-8 sequence

Tags: mysql, encoding, utf-8, lua, latex

I am on Linux Debian and I am trying to print a PDF by extracting some information from my database `linux_krozki`. To do this I first created my database which has `utf8mb4` character set and `utf8mb4_slovenian_ci` collation.

I didn't use `utf8` character set and `utf8_slovenian_ci` based on [this topic](https://medium.com/@adamhooper/in-mysql-never-use-utf8-use-utf8mb4-11761243e434).

```
MariaDB [(none)]> SHOW CREATE DATABASE linux_krozki;
+--------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Database     | Create Database                                                                                       |
+--------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| linux_krozki | CREATE DATABASE `linux_krozki` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_slovenian_ci */ |
+--------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

So now I fill the database table `skupine` with information like this - mind the letter `ž` in column `opombe`:

[image]

When I want to compile a PDF document using LuaLaTeX in conjunction with LuaSQL I get an error because of that character `ž`:

```
! String contains an invalid utf-8 sequence.
l.1 Mo
    en dostop za invalide, prepoved kajenja.
l.39        Opombe: & \luadirect{skupina_opombe(arg[3])}
```

This is weird, because my source files `predracun.lua` and `predracun.tex` are both UTF-8 encoded:

Here is `predracun.tex` source file:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

% package for UTF-8 encoding 
\usepackage[utf8]{luainputenc}

% package for lua   
\usepackage{luacode}
    \directlua{dofile('predracun.lua')}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{rp{11cm}}
        ŽžĐđŠšĆćČč\\
        \luadirect{skupina_opombe()}\\
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

And here is `predracun.lua` source file:

```
function skupina_opombe ()
    package.cpath = package.cpath .. ";/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lua/5.3/luasql/mysql.so"
    luasql = require('luasql.mysql')
    env = assert (luasql.mysql())
    con = assert (env:connect("linux_krozki","ziga","Slovenija123"))

    cur = assert (con:execute("SELECT opombe FROM skupine WHERE id_skupine = (SELECT id_skupine FROM predracuni WHERE id_interesa =1);"))

    vnos = cur:fetch ({}, "a")

    tex.print(
        string.format([[%s]], vnos.opombe)
    )

end
```

I also explicitly specified `\usepackage[utf8]{luainputenc}` in the `predracun.tex`. So how come I still get the error? Mind that error isn't triggered by speciall characters `ŽžĐđŠšĆćČč` but by a `\luadirect{skupina_opombe()}` which reads from a database...

**PS:** I wasn't sure if I should publish this topic on TeX communitiy as it is a hybrid of TeX and programming language Lua.

Comment: If I replace letter `ž` with `Ž`, `š` or `Š` symptoms are the same, But if I replace it with `Đ`, `đ`, `Ć`, `ć`, the PDF will compile but these letters will be displayed as `?` inside the PDF.

Comment: I think I might be missing this: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-connection.html but I am not sure how I can implement this into my Lua file.

Comment: Get the hex of the string, if `ž` becomes `9E`, the character is in latin1/cp1250.  If you get `C5BE`, then you have utf8/utf8mb4.

Comment: This could be checked using hex editor like Okteta or Bless! Good idea!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After studying [MySQL online documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-connection.html) I found out that in MySQL world it is not enough that your database has UTF-8 encoding as well as your program which calls the database!

**We also need to specify the UTF-8 encoding every time we access the database!**

This was a big surprise for me and I managed to solve my problem  by adding one line of code into my `predracun.lua`. This line saved my day:

```
cur = assert (con:execute("SET NAMES 'utf8';"))
```

It actually tells MySQL server that from this point on connection should operate entirely in UTF-8 encoding. So this line has to be located right before a line which reads data from a database:

```
cur = assert (con:execute("SELECT opombe FROM skupine WHERE id_skupine = (SELECT id_skupine FROM predracuni WHERE id_interesa =1);"))
```

The only question that still remains is:

> Are database encodings `utf8` and `utf8mb4` compatible or should I
>   make my database `utf8` insetead of `utf8mb4`? That article recommends I do not... So I will probably rather use `SET NAMES 'utf8mb4`.

Comment: It seems that you must use `utf8mb4` because `utf8` is a limited character set, it is unable to hold unicode characters above U+FFFF

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff - `ŽžĐđŠšĆćČč` are all available in both utf8 and utf8mb4.  (But I agree; use utf8mb4 if at all possible.)

Answer (score 2):

For all European character sets, utf8 and utf8mb4 are "identical".  Those two `CHARACTER SETS` differ for some Chinese characters and some Emoji (plus some obscure characters).

Whereas doing `con:execute("SET NAMES 'utf8';")` right after connecting is valid, it would be better to specify the client's encoding during the connection.  (Sorry, I don't know how to do that in LUA.)

The link you mention just explains that if you want a pile-of-poo to look like  and not be censored to `????`, you must use `CHARACTER SET utf8mb4`, not `utf8`.

Although the Eastern European characters you mention will work equally well in utf8 or utf8mb4, I recommend using utf8mb4.